# Accessing DIV elements of sibling frame

Tags: html

This is probably a very basic question, but I could not get my way around this. I have the following defined in MainPage.jsp file.

```
    <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        </head>

        <frameset rows="44,*,26" cols="*">
           <frame src="SubFrame1.jsp" name="SubFrame1" scrolling="no" id="SubFrame1" />
           <frame src="SubFrame2.jsp" id="SubFrame2" title="SubFrame2" />
        </frameset>

        <noframes>
        <body style="overflow:hidden">
        </body>
        </noframes>

        </html>
```

How can I access any  element defined in one sub frame page (E.g. SubFrame1.jsp) from another (E.g. SubFrame2.jsp)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `javascript`. Use `parent.frame_name`. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/parentExample.htm) you can find a example.

**EDIT:**

Assuming that you have one input called "someinput" in the subframe one:

```
<input type='text' name='someinput' id='someinput' value='my value!' />
```

You can access the value in the subframe two by javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  alert(window.parent.SubFrame1.document.getElementById('someinput').value);
</script>
```

But be aware that using frames is obsolate option. It's better to divide your content with `divs` and use `css` to the style of them.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for your reply and apologies for my delayed one. I tried your solution, but I could not navigate into the window.parent.mainFrame.document.all when I debugged the JS. I only tried these in latest versions of Firefox and Crome. I some how wanted to access the siblings element by something like: x.y.document.getElementByID("divID"). Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun In your case should be `window.parent.SubFrame1`. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I could not navigate to `window.parent.mainFrame.document.all` in your example reference [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/parentExample.htm). So similarly in my example I could not navigate to `window.parent.SubFrame1.document.all`. It gives an undefined error.

Comment: which browser are your using?